# Alinear un boton a la derecha con Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un `CRUD` y necesito alinear un botón a la derecha completamente pero no logro hacerlo, por lo general siempre lo suelo hacer con `ml-auto` pero no me funciona, acá el código:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      Lista de Etiquetas
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-auto">Crear</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En principio la clase `ml-auto` alinea a la derecha , pero esta clase es propia de `flexbox` en [`bootstrap4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) y para utilizar el padre debe tener la clase `d-flex`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body d-flex">
                    Lista de Etiquetas
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-auto">Crear</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otra opción sin `flexbox` es utilizar la clase `float-right`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Lista de Etiquetas
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Crear</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Una opción usando flexbox de Bootstrap es con las clases `d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center` utilizadas en el contenedor, las cuales permiten en este caso que el texto esté a la izquierda y el botón a la derecha, además de mantenerse centradas verticalmente.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      Lista de Etiquetas
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Crear</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```